# Computing the expected value of minimum operations in polynomial time

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

Recently I faced an interesting problem which took me about couple of days of thinking but I couldn't find the polynomial time solution. So I decided to share it with you:

Let

```
S = {s1,s2,...,sn}   0 <= si <= 3
T = {t1,t2,...,tn}   0 <= ti <= 1
```

Now we want to change the elements of S in a way that the following conditions are fulfilled:

```
t1 = s1 mod 2
ti = (si mod 2) xor ( floor(0.5 * s(i-1)) )      2 <= i <= n
```

The only operations allowed are to increase or decrease si by 1 or let it to be unchanged. The goal is to find the minimum number of increasing or decreasing operations which satisfy the above equations for S and T. This task can be simply done using the Dynamic Programming in `O(n)` for any given S and T.

The main problem is "What is the expected value of minimum operations for every given n?". The first Idea is to generate every Sequence of S and T for a given n, after computing the minimum operations for each pair, calculate the expected or average value. but this runs in `O(n8^n)`. Is there a polynomial time algorithm like DP for solving this task?

Comment: Could you motivate the second restriction on `ti`? It looks purely arbitrary and thus makes this problem look uninteresting.

Comment: @RoryDaulton if the second constraint did not exist then this problem would be trivial - it would always only require up to 1 operation, and only on the first element of S

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: Yes, of course, but my comment is not on the existence of a second constraint but on that particular second constraint. I can't think of any actual use for it as it stands now, so I ask for its use.